# Issue with message replication in cluster setup

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-tomee

I have setup a cluster with two nodes. Messages produced on one node are always consumed by single node.(The node which produces the message). I want the message to be consumed in all nodes.

I have a destination (topic) on both nodes.
So any messages raised should be consumed by both nodes.

I am not sure if there is any configuration issue with the way I configured,

```
<broker
    xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        useJmx="true"
        brokerName="mybrokerA"
        useShutdownHook="false"
        persistent="true"
        start="false"
        schedulerSupport="true"
        enableStatistics="false"
        offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="259200000"
        offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="3600000">
    <destinations>
        <topic name="FooTopic" physicalName="FooTopic"/>
    </destinations>

<networkConnectors>
  <networkConnector name="dd" uri="static:(tcp://10.96.10.66:61816,tcp://10.96.10.25:61816)" duplex="true">
   <staticallyIncludedDestinations>
        <topic physicalName="FooTopic"/>
    </staticallyIncludedDestinations>
   </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>
    <transportConnectors>           
        <transportConnector name="default" uri="tcp://10.96.10.66:61816"/>
    </transportConnectors>          
</broker>
```

Same is the file in node2 with ip changed in the transport connector.

tomee file.

ServerUrl = tcp://10.96.10.66:61816
DataSource jdbc/teamsdb
BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:../conf/activemq.xml

Can any one please help me on this. ?